# YouTube API user/channel human readable display name gone

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Previously I had been getting a YouTube user/channel's human readable name using the `$t` field within the `entry` and  `title` fields from an API call like the following:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/_6w3OSoTacXjd42ELqLbGQ?v=2&alt=json

The documentation explains that this title tag should contain:

> a human-readable title for a feed or an entry in a feed

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_title

This used to be the case, but now the title contains the username of the channel/user instead of its human readable name. In the API call eaxmple above the title tag contains `DBZ3333` but the actual human readable name is `Kanal von DBZ3333` and this doesn't appear anywhere in the API response.

I cannot find any announcements or any documenation mentioning this change, is this a bug in the YouTube API?

Is there now any way of getting a user/channel's human readable name using the YouTube API?

Comment: Hmmm... I'll ask internally and find out what might be going on.

Comment: The right folks are looking into it internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Okay, unfortunately this is something that can't easily be reverted. I'm told that in the Data API v3 there will be an additional field for display name in addition to the one for channel title (in the coming weeks), but the v2 behavior needs to stay as-is.

*This was an inadvertent change in behavior, and the engineering team has just written a fix for it. It should be deployed into production in around a week.*

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed, should it have been?

Comment: That's a good point; even though the engineering team said it was fixed, I can reproduce the same issue. I've updated the internal bug I filed asking them to investigate further. Sorry about that.